# identifier mongoose has already been declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
 


  const Lerischema=new mongoose.Schema({
      title:String,
      nickname:String,
      length:Number
  })
  const Leri=mongoose.model('Leri',Lerischema)
  /* const Lerilr= new Leri({title:'dasi',nickname:'ernesto',length:18})
   */
   Leri.insertMany([
       {title:'hirti',nickname:'lix',length:5},
       { title:'gero',nickname:'bivre',length:41},
       { title:'herti',nickname:'mengo',length:12}
])
```

so this is my code using mongoose and in the terminal i constantly recieving this identifier error in the terminal (cmder) , I dont know what the heck is the problem

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: yes it is and I know it is so basic but I dont know the problem:/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should find out if you have defined two 'const mongoose = require ('mongoose'). I have solved this solution (although there are other problems right away)

Comment: This kind of answer/thought are usually posted as a comment and not as a final answer!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know anything about this